# Let $\mathbf{v}=[ 1,2,3 ]^T$ and let $A=\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T.$ Compute $A^r$, $r\in{\mathbb{N}}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$ and let $A=\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T.$ Compute $A^r, \ r\in{\mathbb{N}}$.

According to my book, the answer is $$A^r=\underbrace{\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T...\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T}_{r \ \text{times}}=\mathbf{v}14^{r-1}\mathbf{v}^T=14^{r-1}\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T=14^{r-1}A,$$ because they somehow find that $\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}=|\mathbf{v}|^2=1^2+2^2+3^2=14.$ Why is a vectortranspose times itself equal to a skalar, but a vector times it's transpose is not equal to a scalar? Is it because a matrix of type $1\times3$ multiplied with a matrix of type $3\times 1$ will be a matrix of $1\times 1$ which is just one entry?

I'd just do regular matrix multiplication and obtain:

Let $$\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 14\end{bmatrix}=14.$$

Comment: I don't understand. A vector times its transpose and the transpose times the vector is both times a scalar and gives the same result. Actually $\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T$ is a scalar product (the standard scalar product), thus it's symmetric

Comment: No, matrixmultiplication is not commutative. $vv^T\neq$ scalar.

Comment: Oh my god I'm sorry for this awful error. I didn't think enough before commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because a matrix of type $1\times 3$ multiplied with a matrix of type $3\times 1$ will be a matrix of $1\times 1$

Yes, exactly.

And the other way around: $3\times 1$ times $1\times 3$ gives $3\times 3$